# Grails: Inject application configuration from application.properties into Config.groovy

Tags: grails, configuration

Here is the problem:

For the sake of multiple developers and development environments (developer dependent, developer VM, dev, qa, stage, prod), I want to be able to use application.properties file to inject app confiugration into Config.groovy. Reason why it works for us is that we are using same file for injecting settings in Spring's applicationContext.xml file. I've been trying to accomplish this by follwing in Config.groovy, but still not geting value for neo4j.url from application properties.

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:application.properties",
    "file:${baseDir}/application.properties",
    "file:${basedir}/application.properties"
]


println "neo4j url : ${grailsApplication.config.neo4j.url}"
println "neo4j url : ${neo4j.url}"
```

There must be something I'm doing wrong..

Comment: where do you check value? I mean this `println`, inside `Config.groovy`?

Comment: good point, figured out once I print it from within controller, everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was printing values in Config.groovy, once application loaded everything worked fine, as expected, case closed tnx to Igor.